# How to prevent a WebView losing it's state when the orientation changes

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating a browser. When turning the device using the google chrome app, the webview inside this chrome app doesn't have to reload the webview. How can I achieve this with the webView in my own app?

Comment: Maybe use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in AndroidManifest?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: Sorry for mistake. I should be `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` not `android:configChanges="true"`

Comment: the android doc notes: -Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Comment: isn't there any other way?

Comment: Are you tried to save instance state?

Comment: saving the state of a webview means saving the url and reload it in oncreate of the activity containing the WebView. But the chrome app doesn't have to reload when rotating the device, that's what i want to achieve...

Comment: Wait. I will check something.

Comment: If you are using the same layout use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" this can be avoid if you are using different layout and different configuration (example: the locate) when the screensize or orientation change, otherwise, use it.

Comment: Yes i think in that case `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` is the best solution.

Comment: I decoded AndroidManifest.xml from Chrome app and it uses configChages so you must use it.

Comment: ok thanks i will use it :)